# Foreign key from table A on table A

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table with users

```
users
+------+
 - user_id
 ...
 ...
 - updated_by
```

as I understand column `updated_by` should reference this table on column `user_id`. I'm not sure, that this would be correct, but I don't see any other way. My database uses 3NF.

Thank you all for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely appropriate and correct to have a table have a foreign key relationship back to itself, if that's what's appropriate for your usage.

Comment: But I just can't comprehend what sort of relationship should it be? One to many?

Comment: It's a one-to-one reference.  You have one record, with one column which refers to one record.  One-to-one.

Comment: And `ON UPDATE ... ON DELETE ...` depend on my logic or there is a best choice for that too? In earlier comment today I asked in other answer about that. Would that be correct in current situation `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: @Paul Sonier: Why one-to-one? It maybe one-to-one or one-to-many. From the context i would suggest one-to-many.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with this, it's just a self-referential "foreign" key. The problem is priming the database - there has to be either a root record in the table before you apply the foreign key, or there has to be some way of disabling the foreign key checks when inserting new root records into an otherwise empty table.

The other danger is a mis-applied cascading update or delete. If you start it at the wrong end of the chain, you could wipe out/update large chunks of the table by accident. e.g... you delete the root node, and the delete cascades itself down to all child records.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very common. It's how (usually?) parent/child relationships are implemented.

Another option (if you want to avoid having one or more `"root"` records with `NULL` in the `updated_by` fields), is to move `updated_by` to a second table where both `user_id` and `updated_by` reference `users.user_id` :

```
users
--------
 - user_id (PK)
 ...
 ...


updates
--------
 - user_id (PK)
 - updated_by
 - FK user_id REFERENCES users(user_id)
 - FK updated_by REFERENCES users(user_id)
```

Comment: So if I'm okey with self-contained table, then `ALTER TABLE users ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_users_users ( updated_by ) REFERENCES users( user_id ) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION`